# Find duplicates and remove it applying conditions SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-delete

I'm new to SQL Server, and I'm trying to remove duplicates from a table but with some conditions, and my doubt is on how to apply these conditions to the query.

I need to remove duplicates from the `Users` table, eg:

```
Id    Code    Name   SysName
-----------------------------
1      D1      N1       
2      D1
3      D1      N1       N-1
4      E2      N2
5      E2      N2
6      E2      N2
7      X3
8      X3               N-3    
9
10
11     Z4      W2       N-4-4
12     Z4      W2       N-44
```

In the above table: for D1 code I want to keep the ID=3, which has all columns filled (Code, Name, and SysName) and delete ID=1 and ID=2

For E2 code, I want to keep any of these and remove the two duplicated ones

For X3 code, keep the one which has SysName=N-3

For ID=9, ID=10 (empty code and everything empty, remove all)

For Z4 code, remove ID=11 and keep N-44 Sysname

And the last thing, I've  a FK with other table, so I think that I need first to get all Id's from Users, delete these ids from the second dependent table and finally delete from Users table.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve it? I do not pretend the solution but a structure code or examples/scenarios you have similar to it, any suggestion would be fine for me.

EDIT:

To resume.. I have Users table:

```
Id    Code    Name   SysName
-----------------------------
1      D1      N1       
2      D1
3      D1      N1       N-1
4      E2      N2
5      E2      N2
6      E2      N2
7      X3
8      X3               N-3    
9
10
11     Z4      W2       N-4-4
12     Z4      W2       N-44
```

And I want to keep only:

```
Id    Code    Name   SysName
-----------------------------
3      D1      N1       N-1
4      E2      N2
8      X3               N-3    
12     Z4      W2       N-44
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the expected results? cause it will be great explanation ;)

Comment: Done, Hope it helps thank you!!

Comment: So if you had records 11, 12 with a sysname of N-44 and N-45 how would you know which to pick assuming they both also had W2 names?  To put it simply how can you determine which record to keep if name and sysname are both populated?  Or if One was W1 and the other was W2...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like

```
SELECT Code,
       MAX(ISNULL(Name, '')) Name,
       MAX(ISNULL(SysName, '')) SysName
FROM T
WHERE Code IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Code;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------+------+---------+
| Code | Name | SysName |
+------+------+---------+
| D1   | N1   | N-1     |
| E2   | N2   |         |
| X3   |      | N-3     |
| Z4   | W2   | N-4-4   |
+------+------+---------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d75c05d3826391ecf46f3ad5c5c649e6)**

Comment: Yes! but D1,E2, Z4 could be anything, these are just examples, I'm looking for a generic solution

Comment: While I like the merging of data concept this could get dangerous if Z4 had a name of W1 and W2 with different sysnames, you could be merging records inappropriately.  Put another way; this assumes the max of name and sysname would be the same record for a given code; or it is acceptable for this to occur.

Answer (score 1):

The next query show the list of ids to remove according to the next rules of importance:

1- If the user has all the fields empty/null will be deleted.

2- The user with more fields with errors will be considered first to remove (example SysName cannot contains two -).

3- The user with more fields empty/null will be considered first to remove.

```
;WITH
[Ids]
AS
(
    SELECT
         [U].[Id]
        ,[Importance] =
            CASE
                WHEN [X].[NumberOfFilledFields] = 0
                    THEN -1
                ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [U].[Code] ORDER BY [X].[NumberOfInvalidFields], [X].[NumberOfFilledFields] DESC)
            END
    FROM [Users] AS [U]
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
             [NumberOfFilledFields] =
                + CASE WHEN NULLIF([U].[Code], '') IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                + CASE WHEN NULLIF([U].[Name], '') IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                + CASE WHEN NULLIF([U].[SysName], '') IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            ,[NumberOfInvalidFields] =
                + CASE WHEN [U].[SysName] LIKE '%-%-%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS [X]
)
SELECT
    [Id]
FROM [Ids]
WHERE (1 = 1)
    AND ([Importance] = -1 OR [Importance] > 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://rextester.com/VGEVX55238)
(Any other answer: feel free to borrow the demos to test your answer or use it in yours!  no need to duplicate effort!)

One could use an analytic function/window function like row_number() to assign a row to each record we want and keep all the #1 rows except for those where code is null...  do this with a cte and then just delete.

We determine what to keep by looking at the record having the most data and in case of ties, use the earliest ID.

```
With cte as (
SELECT id, code, name, sysname,
row_number() over (partition by code order by (case when name is not null then 1 else 0 end + case when sysname is not null then 1 else 0 end) desc, ID) RN
FROM users)

Delete from cte where RN <> 1 or code is null;
```

Results in:

```
+----+----+------+------+---------+
|    | ID | Code | Name | Sysname |
+----+----+------+------+---------+
|  1 |  3 | D1   | N1   | N-1     |
|  2 |  4 | E2   | N2   | NULL    |
|  3 |  8 | X3   | NULL | N-3     |
|  4 | 11 | Z4   | W2   | N-4-4   |
+----+----+------+------+---------+
```

One could use the CTE and delete related FK records that would get purged
and then use the cte again and delete the users

Answer (score 1):

This uses window functions and coalesce:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([Id] INT, [Code] CHAR(2), [Name] CHAR(2), [SysName] VARCHAR(10)) 

INSERT INTO @t values
  (1 , 'D1', 'N1', Null   ), (2 , 'D1', Null, Null    ), (3 , 'D1', 'N1', 'N-1'  ), (4 , 'E2', 'N2', Null     ), (5 , 'E2', 'N2', Null    ), (6 , 'E2', 'N2', Null    )
, (7 , 'X3', Null, Null   ), (8 , 'X3', Null, 'N-3'  ) , (9 , Null, Null, Null    ), (10, Null, Null, Null    ), (11, 'Z4', 'W2', 'N-44'), (12, 'Z4', 'W2', 'N-44' )

;WITH t AS (
SELECT DISTINCT  
                [code]
                , COALESCE([name], max([name]) OVER(PARTITION BY [code])) AS [Name]
                , COALESCE([sysname], COALESCE(MAX([sysname]) OVER(PARTITION BY [code], [name]), MAX([sysname]) OVER(PARTITION BY [code]))) AS [SysName]
FROM @t
WHERE [code] IS NOT NULL)
SELECT MIN(t2.id), t.Code, t.Name, t.SysName
from @t t2 
INNER JOIN t ON t.code = t2.code AND ISNULL(t.[Name], 'null') = ISNULL(t2.[Name], 'Null') AND ISNULL(t.[SysName], 'Null') = ISNULL(t2.[SysName], 'Null')
GROUP BY t.Code, t.Name, t.SysName
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to have knowledge of case
then you can change the condition accordingly

you can see the sample code bellow. just twist the case as per your requirements in where clause.

```
;with C as
(
  select Dense_rank() over(partition by code order by id) as rn,*
  from Users
)
delete from C
where rn =
(case 
when (code = 'd1' and name is not null and sysname !='') then  0 
when (code = 'E1' and rn = 1) then  0 
when (code = 'X3' and sysname!='') then 0
when (code = 'z4' and name is not null and sysname !='') then  0 
else rn
end )
```

Output:-

```
    3   D1  N1  N-1
    8   X3      N-3
    11  Z4  W2  N-4-4
    12  Z4  W2  N-44
```